# Broken Images and CSS Only on Live site

Tags: html, css, server, broken-image

When I view my site locally on my laptop, the site looks perfect and works. But once I copy my files to the server, the live site looses the CSS and all the image links are broken. The images and css are properly linked and I have renamed and reuploaded the files several times (thinking it was a broken transfer). This is a project page from my main site and I don't have any issues with any of the other pages. Is this a server issue or a code issue? Any ideas on what this could be/how to fix it?

The problematic page is http://squigua.com/AD/R1NR/norules.html 
The style and photos should leave the first initial screen looking like this:
[black background, centered text, pictures, funky typeface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSyhi.jpg)

Comment: Do you have addblock installed? for me it works fine on firefox (where I don't have any addblockers) but on chrome it blocks the css/ images.  From console: GET http://squigua.com/AD/R1NR/style.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
norules.html:56 GET http://squigua.com/AD/R1NR/smiley.png net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
norules.html:69 GET http://squigua.com/AD/R1NR/images/1RNR-19.jpg net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: yes! that is definitely the problem. i think the file name "AD" is flagging the ad blocker. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that all your resources are in a folder named "AD".

Adblock will just assume you're serving up ads, so it will block ALL resources in that folder.